# HDMI out doesn't give sound 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10, hdmi

I've installed ubuntu on HP-pavilion. It has a ATI video card. I used to run windows7 on it just as a media centre. I want to do the same just with Ubuntu.
I've found multiple topics with similar problems but none of the answers seem to help me.

The output is listed with `aplay -l` and in the configuration screen. But when switching it remains quite.

Anyone?

[image: audio devices]

Answer (score 1):

Try navigating to your sound settings by selecting the volume option on your Menu Bar on the top of your screen, then when the window opens, select your audio device. Its a basic fix that may not work, but its worth a shot.

Comment: I tried that before searching more difficult solutions. Thank for looking at it :)

Comment: Oh okay. Hopefully you find a fix for it! :)